# <Spring jdbc 3.2.8> Issue with sql type and entity type [NumberFormatException]

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I defined an entity class:

```
class Clazz{
    private long id;
    private String cityHash;
    public Clazz(){}
    public Clazz(String cityHash){
        this.cityHash = cityHash
    }
}
```

mysql: table city_hash

```
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_hash` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT'Google city hash64',
```

I use SimpleJdbcInsert to insert a piece of data

```
    private SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(getJdbcTemplate()).withTableName("city_hash").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    Clazz clazz = new Clazz("12040412458563268888")
    Number newId = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(clazz);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; 
Cannot convert class java.lang.String to SQL type requested due to java.lang.NumberFormatException- For input string: "12040412458563268888"; 
nested exception is java. sql.SQLException: Cannot convert class java.lang.String to SQL type requested due to java.lang.NumberFormatException-For input string: "12040412458563268888"
```

I encountered this exception in spring 3+, it can insert data in spring 2.5.

Comment: How should I use SimpleJdbcInsert to insert data correctly or is this a spring bug?